# Python: Saving NGLView image to PNG

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following simple task: save a rendered NGLView frame into a .png file and then read the file.

Following [this](https://github.com/nglviewer/nglview/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-to-make-nglview-view-object-write-png-file) manual I can successfully save an image and open it manually from file explorer. However, in my flow I need to open in using Python and use in downstream jobs right after it was saved. I have the following snippet in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
import nglview as nv
import ipywidgets as w
import time
import threading

from pathlib import Path
```

```
view = nv.demo()
view
```

```
def save_image(view):
    img = view.render_image()
    
    while not img.value:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    
    with open("img.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img.value)

Path("img.png").unlink(missing_ok=True)

thread = threading.Thread(target=save_image, args=(view, ), daemon=False)
thread.start()

open("img.png", "rb").read()
```

```
open("img.png", "rb").read()
```

The problem is that executing cell#3 I get `FileNotFoundError`. I found out that file is read by `open` before it's written in `save_image` func. If I then execute cell#4 **manually** - it works fine. However, if I execute all 4 cells at once (using re-run button in the notebook) - I get the exception. Seems like the image is rendered only when main thread finishes its job.

Adding `thread.join()` leads to infinite loop (i.e. the image is never rendered).
Trying to await for image to be rendered with `while-loop` and `sleep` after the thread was started is also not working.

How can I let Python wait for image to be rendered and saved before reading the file?

python-3.8.10; nglview-3.0.3; OS - Win, MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, JS rendering is invoked only after other jobs are executed, i.e. awaiting for render and then reading a file is not possible. That's why all work with the image should happen in `save_image` function.

See [here](https://github.com/nglviewer/nglview/discussions/1002#discussioncomment-3832985)